# Having trouble iterating backwards through a linked list in java

Tags: java, iterator, iteration, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have an assignment to create a doubly linked list from a single linked list implementation I'm provided with. I got the code working for the most part i.e. it will iterate backwards through the link list. However, the code uses an overloaded add() method which will insert a node at a given index. The problem is I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create a reference to one of these added nodes. Anything added with the overloaded add method will appear when iterated through but won't appear when its iterated backwards.

Here is the add methods.

```
public void add(T element) {

    Node<T> node = new Node(element);

    if (itsFirstNode == null) {
        itsFirstNode = node;
        itsLastNode = node;
    }
    else {
        itsLastNode.setNextNode(node);
        node.setPriorNode(itsLastNode);
        itsLastNode = node;
    }
    size++;
}

public void add(T element, int index) {
    int counter = 0;
    Node<T> newNode = new Node(element);
    Node<T> current = itsFirstNode;
    while (current.getNextNode() != null ) {
        if (counter == index - 1 ){
            break;
        }
        priorNode = newNode;
        current = current.getNextNode();
        counter++;
    }
    newNode.setNextNode(current.getNextNode());
    current.setNextNode(newNode);

    size++;
}
```

This is how the dogs are initializes in the main method.

```
    Dog fifi = new Dog("Fifi", 12, 8);
    Dog butch = new Dog("Butch", 10, 10);
    Dog leonard = new Dog("Leonard", 22, 13);
    Dog spot = new Dog("Spot", 17, 9);

    LinkedList<Dog> myDogList = new LinkedList<Dog>();


    System.out.println(myDogList);
    System.out.println();
    myDogList.add(fifi);

    System.out.println(myDogList);
    System.out.println();

    myDogList.add(butch);
    myDogList.add(leonard);
    myDogList.add(spot);

    System.out.println(myDogList);
    System.out.println();

    Dog jack = new Dog("Jack", 18, 18);

    myDogList.add(jack,1);

    System.out.println(myDogList);
    System.out.println();
```

Here is the result I get with my ListRunner.

```
Just Entered Dog constructor
Leaving Dog constructor
Just Entered Dog constructor
Leaving Dog constructor
Just Entered Dog constructor
Leaving Dog constructor
Just Entered Dog constructor
Leaving Dog constructor


Dog: Fifi , height: 8 weight: 12

Dog: Fifi , height: 8 weight: 12
Dog: Butch , height: 10 weight: 10
Dog: Leonard , height: 13 weight: 22
Dog: Spot , height: 9 weight: 17

Just Entered Dog constructor
Leaving Dog constructor
Dog: Fifi , height: 8 weight: 12
Dog: Jack , height: 18 weight: 18
Dog: Butch , height: 10 weight: 10
Dog: Leonard , height: 13 weight: 22
Dog: Spot , height: 9 weight: 17

Iterating using Iterators!!!
Dog: Fifi , height: 8 weight: 12
Dog: Jack , height: 18 weight: 18
Dog: Butch , height: 10 weight: 10
Dog: Leonard , height: 13 weight: 22
Dog: Spot , height: 9 weight: 17
Iterating backwards using Iterators!!!
Dog: Spot , height: 9 weight: 17
Dog: Leonard , height: 13 weight: 22
Dog: Butch , height: 10 weight: 10
Dog: Fifi , height: 8 weight: 12
End of iteration.
```

EDIT: Code for the iterator.

```
    public class Iterator<T> {

    private LinkedList<T> myList;
    private LinkedList<T>.Node<T> myCurrentNode;

    public Iterator(LinkedList<T> list) {
        myList = list;
        myCurrentNode =  myList.itsFirstNode;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (myCurrentNode != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public boolean hasPrior(){
         if (myCurrentNode/*.getPriorNode()*/ != null)
             return true;
         return false;

    }
    public T next() {
        T data = myCurrentNode.getData();
        myCurrentNode = myCurrentNode.getNextNode();
        return data;
    }
    public T prior() {
        T data = myCurrentNode.getData();
        myCurrentNode = myCurrentNode.getPriorNode();
        return data;
    }
    public void setToEnd() {
       myCurrentNode = myList.itsLastNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your "iterating" code

Comment: In `add(element, index)` you correctly set the values for the nodes' `nextNode` using `setNextNode()`, but you don't set their `priorNode` using `setPriorNode()`... so the new node is isn't inserted into the backwards list.

Comment: I edited and added the iterator. how would you use `priorNode`? because I have tried many different ways of setting a `priorNode` using `Node<T> priorNode = itsLastNode` and then setting something like `priorNode.setNextNode(current);` I've also tried stuff like `newNode.setPriorNode(current);`. Thanks @jonhopkins for responding!

Comment: @Salreth you can use `setPriorNode()` to set the prior nodes at the same place where you set the next nodes. For example, something like `newNode.setNextNode(current.getNextNode()); current.setNextNode(newNode); newNode.getNextNode().setPriorNode(newNode); newNode.setPriorNode(current);`

Comment: @jonhopkins wow that worked. I feel pretty dumb now for overlooking that. Thank you so much for the help.